# Is Java FileInputStream Locking File for writing

Tags: java, scala

I am creating a quick bridge between two separate programs.

One program writes to a file, while my program concurrently reads from it.

It seems that as soon as I call the first read the writing is blocked entirely.

Why is this occurring and what is the workaround?

```
 // Create Named Pipe
 Runtime.getRuntime.exec("mkfifo /tmp/mypipe")

 val stream = new FileInputStream("/tmp/mypipe")

 val in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream))

 // File opened for reading. No blocking at this point.

 while (true) {

   println(in.readLine())

   // File read. Now blocking.

 }
```

**Update:**

This file is actually a named pipe created with `mkfifo /tmp/mypipe`.  I tried using this with a regular `File` and it worked just fine - all data displayed.

I am using a named pipe because I don't want the disk IO overhead.

Comment: Could you show the other program as well?

Comment: @Vlad i don't have source and its not public.  All it does is write no read.  The while loop and lack of proper closing is simple boilerplate.

Answer (score 6):

If I had to bet, I'd say it's a buffering problem.

Initially I was thinking that [`BufferedReader`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/BufferedReader.java.html) might try to fill its entire buffer, but it looks like it's happy as long as it's read something. See the `fill()` method.

If you're using `readLine()`, there's also the question of whether the input you're getting contains newlines.

The other thing that could be happening, depending on how much output the source program produces, is to do with pipe buffering. Would [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe) help?
You can also try ending the source program (e.g. `^C` or such) and then seeing if the destination program prints anything.

[This](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P57906) page suggests that buffering could be an issue:

> However, if a buffered write is used, the buffer is not made available
>   to the reader until the buffer is flushed. This flushing occur.s when
>   more data is written to the buffer than the maximum buffer size
>   (BUFSIZ set in stdio.h), or when the pipe is closed by the writer.

Comment: I tried checking the file length of the data read before and after I inserted a  `Thread.sleep(5000)` between the `BufferedReader` creation and first read - the respective file lengths were 11,498 bytes and 15,521 bytes with 99 and 131 lines.  Therefore the linked answer does not seem to be it.

Comment: Using `$ cat /dev/urandom|hexdump -C   > /tmp/mypipe` as the write command, and your Scala program as the reader, it streams indefinitely. Is there anything in your source program that e.g. makes it want some user input, or anything like that?

Comment: No user input or requests - just a one way tunnel.  I will try using `cat`.

Comment: Seems to work with `cat`.  What could it be that the writer is doing, reading?

Comment: Is it possible it's making assumption about what the output file is, e.g. maybe a terminal, or trying to seek in the file, or anything like that?